# How to put ID numbers in circles on a map

Tags: r, ggmap

I am trying to make a map with 26 sites that have different categories. I would like to display the sites per category with a circle in a different color and add a number in this circle. This number will then relate to a list with sites.

I am familiar with `ggmap` to the point of creating the below map, but I do not see how to add the numbers in the circles. I have checked the FAQ's for ggmap https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ggmap?sort=frequent, but I did not find my answer here.

```
example_sites <- structure(list(`Site No` = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), 
     latitude = c(46.181608,46.171386, 46.179887, 46.181169), 
     longitude = c(8.78852, 8.803413, 8.767505, 8.842291), 
     `Site group` = c("1", "2", "2", "1")), 
     .Names = c("Site No", "latitude", "longitude", "Site group"), 
     class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))

map <- get_map(location ='Locarno, Switzerland', zoom = 13, 
    maptype = "terrain", color = "bw", source = 'google')

p <- ggmap(map)
plot(p)
p + geom_point(data = example_sites, aes(x = example_sites$longitude, y = example_sites$latitude, colour = example_sites$`Site group`), size = 5)
```

This gives the following graph:

[image]

Do you know if it is possible to do what I want (circles in different colours with numbers in them) and if so, how to do it?
If this is not possible with ggmap, I am grateful for tips for other packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you just need to add geom_text() to your code for the plot.

```
p+
  geom_point(data=example_sites, 
             aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, colour=`Site group`), size=5) +
  geom_text(data=example_sites,
            aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, label = `Site No`))
```

[image: plot]

Side note: You don't need the `dataset$` component if you are referencing a variable within the `aes` call.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!